# How to filter array by person's name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

I have this array:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Group A",
    "fields": [
      {
        "value": "color1",
        "name": "Mike"
      },
      {
        "value": "color2",
        "name": "Mark"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Group B",
    "fields": [
      {
        "value": "red",
        "name": "Steve"
      },
      {
        "value": "priority",
        "name": "Laura"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Group C",
    "fields": [
      {
        "value": "red",
        "name": "Paul"
      },
      {
        "value": "priority",
        "name": "Mike"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I'm using an input field to **filter people by their name**. So far I can only filter by "Group" by doing this:

```
post.label.includes(e.target.value)
```

but I'm having a hard time filtering by people's names. The filtering is happening inside **SearchBar** component

For example, if the user enters "**Mike**" I should only see the groups with that user. Like this:

```
Group A
 Mike
Group C
 Mike
```

Here's a [**LIVE DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-cg3fgz?file=/src/data.json). Thanks a lot in advance!

```
const handleSearchChange = (e: any) => {
        if (!e.target.value) return setSearchResults(posts)

         const resultsArray = posts?.filter((post: any)=> {
                // return post.label.includes(e.target.value)
               const result = post.fields.filter((field: any, idx: any) => {
                   return field.name.includes(e.target.value)
                })
                return result
            
            })
        setSearchResults(resultsArray)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken a look at the live demo and seen the issue. Here are the things to change in order to achieve what you want.

First create an `hanldeChange` function in `App.tsx` which would be passed to the `SearchBar` component. The content of this would be

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");

const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setValue(e.target.value)
};

// Search the group anytime value changes
// I advice you debounce if this is making and api call so it doesn't send a request for each alphabet the user types
useEffect(() => {
  if (value) {
    const searchResults = (someJson as Fields[])
      .map((group) => ({
        ...group,
        fields: group.fields.filter(
          (field) => field.name.toLowerCase().match(value.toLowerCase())
        )
      }))
      .filter((group) => group.fields.length > 0);
    setSearchResults(searchResults);
  } else {
    setSearchResults(someJson);
  }
}, [value]);
```

This would be passed to the `SearchBar` component

```
<SearchBar handleChange={handleChange} />
```

Note that `post` and `setSearchResults` are no longer needed.

Refactor the `SearchBar` component to look like this

```
const SearchBar = ({ handleChange }: any) => {
  return (
    <header>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
        }}
      >
        <input type="text" id="search" onChange={handleChange} />
      </form>
    </header>
  );
};
```

Everything should be fine after you do this. Note that there are cleaner ways of achieving this and this solution is based on the demo sample.

Comment: Can you provide a live demo?

Comment: Here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-f7lyfw?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: It doesnt work. If I enter Mike it should ONLY show Mike for each group but it's still showing the Mark in Group A and Paul in Group C

Comment: Did you click the submit button instead of pressing enter?

Comment: Yes I click on submit

Comment: Or you mean the only name present in each group should be mike?

Comment: Yes, only name present in each group should be mike

Comment: First of all I dont need a submit button. Second If I enter "Mike" it searchs for Mike but still shows the other peoples name for each group. Please see my expected output

Comment: Check the edit. It should work as you want it now.

Comment: That is a feature request and that is not what stack overflow is for. I have answered the question you posted here.

Comment: yes, your answer works and the filtering but I don't need to click on a button. I just want to search when the user types, make sense? Can you get rid of your button and have it work as a user type?

Comment: I dont need this:   <button className="search__button">icon</button>

Comment: You can check the sandbox. Ill edit my answer here also

Comment: I just checked your sandbox and I see that I dont need to click on the button anymore which is good, but it's not working. If I enter letter "m" it doesnt search for users which name has "m" but it shows "No Matching Posts" message which is wrong

Comment: You can check again. I also edited the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you looking for.
We need to process each group and its people's names individually. So, instead of using **filter**, we use **map** to iterate through each group. Then we filter the people's Names within each group.

```
const handleSearchChange = (e:any) => {
    if (!e.target.value) return setSearchResults(posts);

    const resultsArray = posts?.map((post:any) => {
        const matchingFields = post.fields.filter((field:any) => {
            return field.name.includes(e.target.value);
        });

        if (matchingFields.length > 0) {
            return {
                label: post.label,
                fields: matchingFields,
            };
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }).filter(Boolean);

    setSearchResults(resultsArray);
};
```

Comment: Your asnwer filters the groups but doesnt work as expected. If I enter "Mike" I should only see Mike for each group but it still shows the other people's names for the other groups. Please see my expected output in my question

Comment: This code should filter the groups and people's names correctly.

Comment: Thank you mate, very much a ppreciated! I'm voting up your answer :)

Answer (score -2):

You will need to loop through each fields inside the post array to find people with their name, here is a naive implementation:

```
function searchByName(name, data) {
  const results = [];

  data.forEach(({ fields }) => {
    fields.forEach(({ name: fieldName }) => {
      if (fieldName.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())) {
        results.push({ fields });
      }
    });
  });

  return results;
}
```

and your `handleSearchChange` function should be like this

```
const handleInputChange = (e: any) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setSearchTerm(value);
    setSearchResults(searchByName(value, data));
  };
```